# How does page.thumb.319.319.png get resolved in Adobe AEM?

Tags: aem, sling

I can't seem to figure out how Adobe AEM (formerly CQ) is resolving the thumb Url.

Given the following Url:

```
/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en.thumb.319.319.png
```

"en" is a reference to the content which relies on the `geometrixx-outdoors/components/page_home` sling:resourceType.

"thumb", "319" and "319" are selectors, but the component "page_home" does not have a matching jsp such as thumb.png.jsp to handle the request.

page_home inherits from `geometrixx-outdoors/components/page` which in turn inherits from `foundation/components/page`. The later has a jsp called `thumbnail.jpg.jsp` but that isn't a match either.

Then there is this strange directory (i.e., it isn't a component) called `/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page` where we find `thumb.png.jsp`. According to some logging I added, this script is participating in the request; *though I am not sure how*. It simply includes the proxy.jsp which includes the jcr:content node.

I suspect that including jcr:content means a call to:

```
/content/info-site/en/_jcr_content.thumb.319.319.png
```

At this point, I am unclear what happens.  It seems like a default GET.java must kick in or something. However, I can't find a `_jcr_content.png.jsp` or `png.GET.java`. There is a class at `/var/classes/org/apache/jsp/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/thumb_png_jsp.java` which looks like it does the work, but I am just not sure how it gets called.

EDIT: Just realized that `/var/classes/org/apache/jsp/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/thumb_png_jsp.java` is the compiled version of the aforementioned `thumb.png.jsp` so I guess that is a dead end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is resolved not through a jsp but through the  com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.servlets.ThumbnailServlet servlet component.

This servlet is registered to respond to the sling/servlet/default resourceType and thumb selector. so it will basically respond to any request with that selector.

you can look for it in the component list of the osgi web console

Comment: Thanks! I tracked down the ThumbnailServlet class in the cq-wcm-core-5.5.6.jar where the OSGI-INF serviceComponents.xml registers it to the "thumb" selector with "gif", "png", or "jpg" extensions.